# Chaining transform on a tuple with a certain chance of applying the transform, with the possibility of registering new transforms

Tags: python-3.x

### Presentation

Here is an implementation of some pre processing logic. The real use case is to apply online augmentation in a neural network context, that applies a chain of transforms on a pair  `(feature, ground_truth)`. I simplified in that example to chain transforms on a pair `(a,b) Tuple[int,float]`, but the idea is similar.

#### What the code below does :

- offers a `RandomTransform` object, that chains transform on a tuple of argument `(a,b)`
- those transforms are applied with a certain probability set by the user
- an user can register a new transform using the provided decorators.

There is a small usage example in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part of the script.

#### What I like about this implementation:

- it is pretty flexible, as it is easy to register a new transform
- it is light to use : no need to create subclass, etc.

#### What I don't like:

- registered functions must follow a strict signature.
- the constructor does not have a set of well defined argument: IDEs and language servers can't infer what `kwargs` are valid or not. Not cool for the developer using it.
- That code does not look super adaptable : what if I need to apply a set of transform on a triplet `(a,b,c)` instead of the pair `(a,b)`.

### Code:

````py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
"""
Apply a chain of random transform to a pair (A,B) 
"""
import math
import random
from typing import Callable, Tuple

_GLOBAL_TRANSFORM = {}


def register_transform_a(fct: Callable) -> Callable:
    """Register a transform for a, and adapt it to work on a tuple (a,b)

    The function returned by the decorator will accept two arguments (a,b) and return
    a tuple (fct(a), b).

    Args:
        fct (Callable): the transform function. Must accept one argument a and return
        the single transformed argument

    Returns:
        Callable: The transform function adapted to a tuple (a,b)
    """

    def adapted_fct(a, b):
        return fct(a), b

    _GLOBAL_TRANSFORM.update({fct.__name__: adapted_fct})
    return fct


def register_transform_b(fct: Callable) -> Callable:
    """Register a transform for b, and adapt it to work on a tuple (a,b)

    The function returned by the decorator will accept two arguments (a,b) and return
    a tuple (a, fct(b)).

    Args:
        fct (Callable): the transform function. Must accept one argument b and return
        the single transformed argument

    Returns:
        Callable: The transform function adapted to a tuple (a,b)
    """

    def adapted_fct(a, b):
        return a, fct(b)

    _GLOBAL_TRANSFORM.update({fct.__name__: adapted_fct})
    return fct


def register_transform_ab(fct: Callable) -> Callable:
    """Register a transform for a tuple (a,b)

    Args:
        fct (Callable): the transform function. Must accept two arguments a,b and return
        a tuple (a,b)

    Returns:
        Callable: The transform function
    """
    _GLOBAL_TRANSFORM.update({fct.__name__: fct})
    return fct


@register_transform_a
def square_A(a: int) -> int:
    """Demo function: Square the argument"""
    return a ** 2


@register_transform_b
def sqrt_B(b: float) -> float:
    """Demo function: return square root of the argument"""
    return math.sqrt(b)


@register_transform_ab
def fct_with_AB(a: int, b: float) -> Tuple[int, float]:
    """Function where the transform of a depends on b and vice-versa"""
    return int(a * b), a / b


class RandomTransformer:
    """An object chaining transforms, where each transform is applied with a probability

    The transformer applies its transform on tuple (a,b)
    Each available function is registered with a decorator. 
    The Constructor expects the name of a registred function and a probability of 
    applying that function
    Example : 
    ```
    transformer = RandomTransformer(square_A=0.5)
    ```
    will create a RandomTransformer object that applies the transorm `square_A` with a
    50% probability. 

    Args:
        **kwargs: key as registered function with the decorators `register_transform_a`
            `register_transform_b`, `register_transform_ab`. Value as the probability 
            of applying that transform
        
    Raise:
        ValueError: if the key of **kwargs is not a registered function
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        not_valid = [
            fct_name for fct_name in kwargs if fct_name not in _GLOBAL_TRANSFORM
        ]
        if not_valid:
            raise ValueError(
                f"The functions {not_valid} are not registered\n"
                f"You can register them using the registering decorators\n"
                f"Currently registered : {list(_GLOBAL_TRANSFORM.keys())}"
            )
        self.transform_fcts = {
            _GLOBAL_TRANSFORM[fct_name]: prob
            for fct_name, prob in kwargs.items()
            if fct_name in _GLOBAL_TRANSFORM
        }

    def transform(self, a: int, b: float) -> Tuple[int, float]:
        """Chain transforms on the arguments a,b 
        
        The transform used are declared at the construction of the RandomTransformer

        Args:
            a (int): an int
            b (float): a float

        Returns:
            Tuple[int, float]: a tuple (a,b) after various transforms applied on it 
        """
        for fct, prob in self.transform_fcts.items():
            if random.random() < prob:
                a, b = fct(a, b)
        return a, b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tuple_to_transform = (2, 3.5)
    transformer = RandomTransformer(square_A=0.5, sqrt_B=0.5, fct_with_AB=0.5)
    a, b = transformer.transform(*tuple_to_transform)
    print(a, b)

    # I want to register a new transform
    @register_transform_ab
    def set_to_null(a, b):
        return 0, 0.0

    set_to_null_sometimes = RandomTransformer(set_to_null=0.01)
    a, b = set_to_null_sometimes.transform(*tuple_to_transform)
    print(a, b)
````

Comment: Rather than providing `simplified code` please provide that actual working code from the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is over-designed. There's not really a point to registering functions, and there's also not a point to distinguishing between "functions that only modify [a/b/both]". Given your current usage (which is all we can go on, in Code Review), just:

- make bare, undecorated functions
- pass references to them into your constructor as a sequence, not a dictionary. A dictionary misrepresents this data structure; lookup is never performed by key.
- `func` is a friendlier abbreviation than `fnct`/`fct`.

As an example,

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
"""
Apply a chain of random transform to a pair (A,B)
"""
import math
import random
from typing import Callable, Tuple

ResultPair = Tuple[float, float]
PairFunction = Callable[[float, float], ResultPair]
FunctionProb = Tuple[PairFunction, float]


def square_A(a: float, b: float) -> ResultPair:
    """Demo function: Square the argument"""
    return a ** 2, b


def sqrt_B(a: float, b: float) -> ResultPair:
    """Demo function: return square root of the argument"""
    return a, math.sqrt(b)


def func_with_AB(a: float, b: float) -> ResultPair:
    """Function where the transform of a depends on b and vice-versa"""
    return int(a * b), a / b


class RandomTransformer:
    def __init__(self, *funcs: FunctionProb):
        self.transform_funcs = funcs

    def transform(self, a: float, b: float) -> ResultPair:
        for func, prob in self.transform_funcs:
            if random.random() < prob:
                a, b = func(a, b)
        return a, b


def main():
    tuple_to_transform = (2, 3.5)
    transformer = RandomTransformer(
        (square_A, 0.5),
        (sqrt_B, 0.5),
        (func_with_AB, 0.5),
    )
    a, b = transformer.transform(*tuple_to_transform)
    print(a, b)

    # I want to register a new transform
    def set_to_null(a, b):
        return 0, 0

    set_to_null_sometimes = RandomTransformer(
        (set_to_null, 0.01),
    )
    a, b = set_to_null_sometimes.transform(*tuple_to_transform)
    print(a, b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Using this simpler approach, you can even pass lambdas, i.e.

```
    set_to_null_sometimes = RandomTransformer(
        (
            lambda a, b: (0, 0),
            0.01
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks foir the reply. Your comments are spot on. `This is over-designed`: this is what I was afraid of. I guess allowing user to pass functions by references also allow them to use curried functions with `partial`, which is even more flexible. The only thing I don't like about your design is the fact that the signature of the function passed as an argument must follow a strict signature `func(a,b)` even if the function does not depends on `b`.

Comment: The last point is easy enough to work around: if you care so much about having univariate functions, make a `with_a` and `with_b` wrapper.